# How to check if a closure is defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

When I want to check if a variable is defined I do it like

```
if(myVar)
    ...
```

but

```
if(myClosure())
    ...
```

will obviously check what the closure returns, not itself.

What is the right syntax to check if a closure is defined?

Comment: is `if(myClosure)` not acceptable for you? as far as functions are first-class-citizens in JS, it will work

Comment: the use of the word closure in here is making my head hurt a little but I'm low on coffee

Comment: Second that, and I really wonder why it's used here instead of `function`.

Comment: Was wondering about the same exactly. what is the difference between checking if a "closure" is defined or if a "function" is defined?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that the variable contains a function, it is still a variable. Just don't call it.

```
if (myClosure) {
```

This will throw a reference error if the variable is undeclared as well as undefined. You might prefer:

```
if (typeof myClosure !== "undefined") {
```

If you want to check if it is a function or not, then:

```
if (typeof myClosure === "function") {
```

There is no way to tell if a function closes over any variables or not though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to determine if a symbol is defined in a scope, then you're better off with

```
if (typeof symbol !== "undefined")
```

In strict mode, just testing a symbol that's not defined as a parameter or variable in some enclosing lexical scope is an error. When you use `typeof` however it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting

> What is the right syntax to check if a closure is defined?

as

> How do I know if I'm not in the global scope?

```
var __test_if_global__ = {};
if (__test_if_global__ === window.__test_if_global__) {
    // you are in global scope
    // delete window.__test_if_global__;
} else {
    // you are not in global scope
}
```

If you just want to check you can reference certain variables, do the usual check as you would for polyfills etc

Comment: The global scope by definition is always available everywhere. When you reference a variable JavaScript travels up the scope hierarchy all the way up to window (in browsers) until it finds that variable. In this case you are literally comparing a variable with itself, it'll throw an error if it is undeclared. It'll return true if it equals 'undefined' and is uninitialised.

Answer (score -1):

A closure is just a variable whose value is a function. If you want to check if the name is defined as a function, use:

```
if (typeof myClosure == 'function')
```

Comment: This will trigger a ReferenceError

Comment: @Tiborg — Only if the variable is *undeclared*.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't clear enough. But still, if the variable is undeclared, then the execution of your script is interrupted, which I'm sure is not the desired result when simply checking if a variable is declared or not.

Comment: I've changed by answer to use `typeof`

Answer (score -1):

That depends upon how you have declared the function.

If you use a `function declaration`, then the function is always available, from compile time on.

```
if (myTestFunction()) {
  // do stuff
}

function myTestFunction() {
  return true;
}
```

On the other hand, if you are using a `function expression`, then that expression must be evaluated first.

```
var myTestFunction = function() {
  return true;
}

if (myTestFunction()) {
  // do stuff
}
```

The third option is if you are passing in a function reference INTO another function, like a callback:

```
function doIt(callbackFunction) {
  if (typeof callbackFunction === "function") {
    callbackFunction(); // execute it.
  }
}
```